HandleSubmit not working with vee-validate on Vue3+Vite
I try to submit a register form using vee-validator to validate the form data, but the handleSubmit function from vee-validator doesn't return or log nothing.
Here's my code:
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { User } from '@/models/user';
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/client/user';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useForm } from 'vee-validate';
import * as yup from 'yup';

const schema = yup.object({
    name: yup.string().required('Name is required'),
    surnames: yup.string().required('Surname is required'),
    birthdate: yup.date().nullable().required('Birthdate is required').transform((value, originalValue) => originalValue === '' ? null : value),
    email: yup.string().email('Email is not valid').required('Email is required'),
    password: yup.string().min(8, 'Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.').required('Password is required'),
    passwordConfirmation: yup.string()
        .oneOf([yup.ref('password'), undefined], 'Passwords must match')
        .required('Password confirmation is required'),
});

const { handleSubmit, defineField, meta, errors } = useForm({
    validationSchema: schema
});


const [name, nameAttrs] = defineField('name');
const [surnames, surnamesAttrs] = defineField('surnames');
const [email, emailAttrs] = defineField('email');
const [password, passwordAttrs] = defineField('password');
const [passwordConfirmation, passwordConfirmationAttrs] = defineField('passwordConfirmation');

const onSubmit = handleSubmit(values => {
    console.log('Handling submit:', values);
    console.log("Form submitted");
    console.log("Values:", values);
    console.log("Is form valid?", meta.value.valid);
});
</script>


<template>
    <section class="form-section">
        <div class="form-container">
            <h1 class="form-title">Create an account</h1>
            <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" novalidate>
                <input type="text" v-model="name" v-bind="nameAttrs" placeholder="Your name" class="input-field" required>
                <span v-if="errors.name" class="error-message">{{ errors.name }}</span>

                <input type="text" v-model="surnames" v-bind="surnamesAttrs" placeholder="Your surnames" class="input-field" required>
                <span v-if="errors.surnames" class="error-message">{{ errors.surnames }}</span>

                <input type="email" v-model="email" v-bind="emailAttrs" placeholder="Your email" class="input-field" required>
                <span v-if="errors.email" class="error-message">{{ errors.email }}</span>

                <input type="password" v-model="password" v-bind="passwordAttrs" placeholder="Password" class="input-field" required>
                <span v-if="errors.password" class="error-message">{{ errors.password }}</span>

                <input type="password" v-model="passwordConfirmation" v-bind="passwordConfirmationAttrs" placeholder="Confirm password" class="input-field" required>
                <span v-if="errors.passwordConfirmation" class="error-message">{{ errors.passwordConfirmation }}</span>

                <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Create an account</button>
                <p class="link-text">Already have an account? <a href="/login" style="color: #007BFF;">Login here</a></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

The onSubmit method should print in the console the values from the handleSubmit, but it doesn't work.

It requires an extra set of brackets.
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(values => {
    console.log('Handling submit:', values);
})();

When you call handleSubmit from your form library, it doesn't immediately execute the form submission logic. Instead, it returns a new function that, when called, will execute the form submission. This returned function is the one that actually performs the form submission logic, such as validation, gathering form values, and calling your provided callback with these values.
